# DIV won't bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[My blog](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) has popup divs and the divs should bottom but they don't :( The bottom will bottom but the content will stay up so the div just stretches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome.
I checked the jquery code and I could make it work with two changes:

1) animate the bottom css attribute insead of top
2) remove the 'px' at the end of the expression assigned to bottom/top navigation.
The changed script would be:

```
$(function () {
        $('.bubbleInfo').each(function () {
            var distance = 10;
            var time = 250;
            var hideDelay = 500;
            var hideDelayTimer = null;
            var beingShown = false;
            var shown = false;
            var trigger = $('.trigger', this);
            var info = $('.popup', this).css('opacity', 0);
            $([trigger.get(0), info.get(0)]).mouseover(function () {
                if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                if (beingShown || shown) {
                    // don't trigger the animation again
                    return;
                } else {
                    // reset position of info box
                    beingShown = true;
                    info.css({
                        display: 'block'
                    }).animate({
                        bottom: '-=' + distance,
                        opacity: 1
                    }, time, 'swing', function() {
                        beingShown = false;
                        shown = true;
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }).mouseout(function () {
                if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    hideDelayTimer = null;
                    info.animate({
                        bottom: '-=' + distance,
                        opacity: 0
                    }, time, 'swing', function () {
                        shown = false;
                        info.css('display', 'none');
                    });
                }, hideDelay);
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

P.S: I verified this and it works in Chrome and FF now.

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH! But I need sort of the "up" effect, anyway to make it work with the up effect :(

Comment: Also, the popup goes a little below the browser bottom, making the scroll bar appear... I tried margins and tops in the css but it sort of screws with the bubble. Any way to move the popup up just a tad so its level?

Comment: May be I am missing something, but am unable to visualize the difference in both versions.

Comment: For the issue with scrollbar set the variable var distance = 0;

Comment: I just have to set the var distance = -10; to make it go up. :))

Comment: All fixed! I just set the distance to -10, hid the scroll bar and set bottom:-10px;

Comment: Damn I have another problem. It works, but after you hover over the post for around 4-5 times it starts to go up and up and up.

Comment: :) I will also keep looking at it and let you know once I figure out bsomething.

Comment: Ok I figured out that each time it carries out the animation, it thinks the bottom was where it last was. So everytime you hover, thats the new bottom so it keeps going -10px from the "bottom" even though it's not the bottom. I have bottom:-10px; and var distance = 10 ;

Comment: So why dont you set the bottom to 0 after the mouse over event is fired using a animate callback?

Comment: I'm terrible with javascript and don't exactly know how :( I am sorry that sounds so stupid but I'm just trying to teach myself.

Comment: I'm just a 16 year old... I did finish a Visual Basics course but that didn't exactly do too much.

Comment: No problem. After the line info.css('display', 'none'); add the following line info.css('bottom', '0px'); in your mouseout handler.

Comment: I did info.css("bottom', '-10px'); and it fixed it. Thanks so much Cybernate your seriously the best on here. Nobody is really nice and your so helpful and understanding. I'll make sure to study up more on my javascript so I won't ask such stupid questions. Thanks again and I will definatley bookmark your profile so I know who to go to. Thanks so much! Your seriously the best. I couldn't ask for more!!

Comment: :) Glad that you got it figured out on your own.

Comment: Lol I just know the numbers your the true brain! I would nominate you for moderator but I don't know how :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant, but I am getting this error in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _popupControl is not defined  http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com/:730
```

The relevant line is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">_popupControl();</script>
```

(which is calling a function that is indeed undefined)

Comment: Nope thats just Tumblr :( They put that in all of their pages by default.

Comment: Ah, sorry I couldn't be of more use.